# PyScript can't find the element id

Tags: javascript, python, quarto, pyscript

I have written the following code, which is not very different from an HTML file.  It is technically a Quarto file, `.qmd`, but it renders to an HTML file and I don't suspect this has to do with the issue that I'm encountering.

```
---
title: "The New Free Fall Hypothesis"

format:
    html:
        include-in-header:
            - header.html
---

<py-script src="./acc_main.py"></py-script>

<input type="text" id="3dinput">10,20,30</input>
<button id="3dplotbutton" py-click="show_plt()" class="py-button">Set camera</button>
<div id="3dplot"></div>
```

Also in the Quarto project's `_quarto.yml` file I've added every `.py` file as a resource.

In `header.html` I've loaded all the necessary stuff like PyScript and matplotlib.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script> 
<py-config>
    packages = ["matplotlib"]
</py-config>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
```

And then in my `acc_main.py` file I wrote this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import js

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

x_data = np.random.randint(0,100,(500,))
y_data = np.random.randint(0,100,(500,))
z_data = np.random.randint(0,100,(500,))

ax.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

def show_plt():
    display(fig, target="3dplot", append=False)
```

When I render the page and click the button, I get the error:

```
pyodide.ffi.JsException: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#3dplot' is not a valid selector.
```

So essentially it looks like everything is working up to a pretty strange point for it to break.  It's loading all the libraries, it's running all the code, it seems to even understand the document object from `js`.  It seems to just not be able to find the object with id `3dplot`.

It has successfully found document ids in other settings that didn't involve a button.  So I kind of guess that the function is being called in some context where it can't see the HTML objects.  But then I look at this example which is working:

https://pyscript.com/@adec3dd4-c366-46d3-9d45-84d3b0996a43/554f713f-bc03-410c-9559-d94c7a3626a3/latest

and it's accessing document objects in basically the same way as I am.  So then I'm really confused about the source of the error.

It also looks like perhaps that `#` is not just from rendering the error but perhaps it's being inserted somewhere along the way and causing the error.  But I can't imagine why what would be happening.

---

[Edit, further thoughts:]

Since there is some possibility that whatever Quarto is doing to render the page is causing the issue, it occurred to me that I could render the page and then just look at the rendered HTML.  I'll post it if anyone thinks it's helpful -- but predictably, there's a ton of irrelevant code there.

But what I think is the important thing that I observe from the HTML is that there is a div element with id `3dplot`.  So I think this confirms that Quarto isn't the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized what it is -- dumb mistake (although I don't know much JS so that's why I didn't realize what was happening).  You can't have ids that start with numbers.  Change the `3dinput` to `threedinput` and now it works.